# How can i combine the colours of one raster with values from another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, fme-form, raster-conversion

I have two Tiffs with data from the same area. One is in colour and when I use the identify shows a 'color index' number (eg. 141), then Color(a,r,g,b)(eg. 255,90,255,0). The other tiff contains a numerical value for the cell. I want a raster that contains both the colour info from the first tiff, and the numerical values from the second. Is there a way to add attributes from another raster or create a new raster that borrows from these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [building a raster attribute table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009t00000009000000)? You can add/delete fields and join tables.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it depends if there is a bijection between the values of your raster or not.

If the color indices always correspond to the same numerical value, then you can use Barbarossa's solution (joining a look up table to the raster attribute table). If you don't know the look up table a priori, [zonal statistics as table](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm) will create the table for you.

If there is no "one to one" relationship between the two rasters, you can build a multiband raster based on [composite band(management)](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/composite_bands_data_management_.htm)